# значение слова разварза

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы уточнить моё понимание слова разварза. 
 Так говорят о человеке несобранном, неопрятном.

В талышском, полагаю и в роськом языке слово варз означает месить, рыхлить, мять.

Спасибо.

Comment: Так говорят... Кто говорит?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как в талышском, а вот в карельском и олонецком наречии варжа/варза-   "плохой, невзрачный или очень молодой жеребенок"( из карельск. varza "жеребенок", фин. varsa, см. Калима 84).

варза́ть по Фасмеру-"делать небрежно, плохо, пачкать, шутить", из русск. заимств. лтш. varzât "делать плохо, тяп-ляп" (М. – Э. 4, 482). 
Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.http://vasmer.slovaronline.com/%D0%92/%D0%92%D0%90/1638-VARZ

По Далю то же самое:    ВАРЗАТЬ — или варзакать что, вят., курск., тамб. варакать, вараксать, варганить, вахлять, делать плохо, как ни попало; | варзать вологод. дурить, шалить, проказить, прокудить; ся, возиться с чем, работать неуспешно, медленно. Варза •об. варзун муж.… …   Толковый словарь Даля

В этимологическом словаре:  Разварза, ж - неряшливая, неопрятная женщина У него жена такая разварза и плохая хозяйка, в доме и дети неухожены Теренг Ульян , 1970 РазварзаЙ, м Неопрятный и неуклюжий человек Нижегор , 1840 
http://urokirus.com/online/srng/72-33-pro-raz/15465-raz-raz.html

Comment: Надо ли понимать из Вашего ответа, что разварза это "плохо сделанный жеребенок". В разделе "этимология" хотелось бы узнать о изначальном значении слова, его внутренней форме.

Comment: Кстати, знание талышского языка только обогатит Ваши познания, все таки изначальная, существенная и древнейшая составляющая русского языка.

Comment: Из моего ответа следует, что варза-неуклюжий жеребёнок, а разварза - тот, кто всё делает неуклюже, тяп-ляп, не по-хозяйски.

Comment: Осталось выделить корень слов и раскрыть его внутреннюю форму. Заодно и словарь обозначить.